# Birt - How to format default date parameter as yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: reporting, birt

I want my parameter default to be the first day of this year so I put in the formula:

BirtDateTime.firstDayOfYear(BirtDateTime.today())

And I'd like the default to be displayed in yyyy-MM-dd format so the users know what format to enter.

However when I run the preview it shows the default as "Jan 1, 2012".

Here is a screen shot of my parameter settings, and a screen shot of the report:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of BIRT do you have? I have just tried setting up a date parameter in BIRT 3.7.1 as shown in the screenshot, and it displays the start date as 2012-01-01.

Comment: How do I tell which version I have?  I downloaded and installed this file eclipse-reporting-indigo-SR1-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz (if that helps)

Comment: check version: help - about eclipse -installation details- plug-ins

Answer (score 3):

You can use Formatter which is a birt function

```
var now = new Date();
Formatter.format(now, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Another answer is here:

http://eclipse.org/birt/documentation/tutorial/tutorial-12.php

basically all you have to do is add a new data field.  Make it a DateTime and add `new Date( )` as the function.  In the properties there is a tab called "Format DateTime".  You can choose your format there.

I know there's been struggle with this issue across the web so I wanted to give as much info as possible.